# string input from Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i Want to make a very simple script that will do the following:

1- I have a List Named tries = ["First", "Second", "Last"]

2- I want the user will make an input string for each try

so I made script as below:

```
print("You got 3 Guessing tries to guess What is My Name")

tries = ["First", "Second", "Last"]

for x in tries:
    Names = str(input(x,"Guess ?"))

    print(Names)
```

but it seems that Python doesn't accept this line: Names = str(input(x,"Guess ?"))

so any suggestions how to make the Questions to be appearing to the user as:  "First Guess?", then "Second Guess?", then "last guess?"

Comment: `input` isn't like `print` with varying arguments. Concatenate or format the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first** off the str() is not needed because input always outputs a string

**secondly** this is python 3.x not 2.7 (in the tagging)

**third** the issue you are having is you are trying to give input 2 parameters, this works with print and that throws new python coders off but other functions won't allow it. you can fix it by simply adding the two strings together like this `input(x+"Guess ?")`

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function takes only **one** arguments. Here, you give two to it.

I'm guessing that what you want to do is

```
print("You got 3 Guessing tries to guess What is My Name")

tries = ["First", "Second", "Last"]

for x in tries:
    Names = str(input("{} Guess ?".format(x))) 

    print(Names)
```

If you want more about `format`: [on devdocs](http://devdocs.io/python~3.5/library/functions#format)

Matt

Comment: Needs more parentheses.